# Java EE Entity Manager does not update an entity from Callable thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

When creating threads using the Java Callable interface, I am having problems where the properties of an entity I have updated are not synced to the database, however when I do the work in the initial thread, they are. An example I have created below:

```
package peter.ford.entityupdate;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;


@Named
@Stateless
public class EntityUpdateBean {
    
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="peter.ford_EntityUpdate_war_1PU")
    private EntityManager em;
    
    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService mes;
    
    private String newName;

    public String getNewName() {
        return newName;
    }

    public void setNewName(String newName) {
        this.newName = newName;
    }
    
    public void update() {        
        UpdateThread t = new UpdateThread();        
        mes.submit(t);
    }
    
    private class UpdateThread implements Callable {

        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            
            TypedQuery<Widget> q = em.createQuery("select w from Widget w", Widget.class);

            List<Widget> widgets = q.getResultList();

            try {
                for ( Widget w : widgets) {
                    w.setName(newName);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return 1;
        }        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Class Widget is the entity:

```
package peter.ford.entityupdate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Widget implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

If I change the code so that the work of looking up the entities and then setting the name is done from the `update()` method of EntityUpdateBean, the changes are updated in the database instantly. No errors appear to be raised, and following the thread in the debugger I can see that it is receiving a list of entities and updating them.

More broadly speaking, is this even the correct approach to update entities from a thread? In this case it is a trivial example, but I have a larger project where I need to update entities in bulk, while checking against data held on a disk for each one, and wish to do this in multiple threads reading from a queue, for performance reasons.

Comment: Entities obtained in one thread are linked to a unit of work (context) that prevents them from being used in other threads.

Comment: But in my above example the entities are selected in the TypedQuery, and then updated in the same thread. I have also tried moving the injection of the EntityManager to the thread, so that all the entity work is done in one thread, but still the database will not update.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue. I can not update or create entities in a task executed outside of the main thread.